# How to manage two different view in single display for single field type?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-views

I am new for Drupal.

I have one page

[My Main Page](http://www.coyotesprague.cz/en)

This is a view of content Type fotogallery.

When I click on any event Title like(FRIDAY 24-05-2013) it goes to that event page where it shows all images for that particular event.
Here it shows slide show for those all Images.
Now the Problem is that,
I want slideshow as well as all images under the slideshow in grid or table format.

I have attached snap of configuration of view also Content Type's Manage Display Page snap

Any one can do it?

This is a configuration of this view

[image: View Configuration]

This is Manage Display of Content Type 
[image: Mange Display]

Please help me.

Regards,

Nisarg

Answer (score 1):

In the view options page change the *Show* from *fields* to **table or grid**.